# Excel - Adding up numbers until cetain condition found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I probable have a simple question if you know the answer to it, but I'm kind off stuck myself and I wasn't able to find anything about it on the internet.

So, I have a excel sheet like the following:

```
Stop?     Number
0         2
0         5
1         7
0         3
1         0
0         12
0         1
0         1
1         4

Totals
1st       14   (2+5+7)
2nd       3    (3+0)
3th       18   (12+1+1+4)
```

As you may already have noticed, I need to count the numbers in the Number colum until I find a 1 in the Stop colum, and save those within the 'fist'/'2nd'/'3th'/etc..
I have tried a lot of other solutions and own ideas but nothing lead to the correct answer.

I hope someone can help me,

Thanks,
Merijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper column and `SUMPRODUCT`. With reference to the figure, the important formulas are:

C2: `=1`

C3: `=C2+A2`  (copy downwards).

F2: `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$10)*($C$2:$C$10=E2))`  (copy downwards).

[image]

Comment: Great solution! Since the number change, I used a 'IF(A3=1; C1+1; C1)' to create the helper colum.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 4 columns :

A(stop) B(cumulated stop) C(number) D(cumulated number)

0           0                             2                2

0           0                             5                7

1           1                             7                14

0           1                             3                3

1           2                             0                3

0           2                             12              12

0           2                             1                13

0           2                             1                14

1           3                             4                18

**B :**

- B(1) = A(1)
- B(N) = B(N-1) + A(N)

**D :**

- D(1) = C(1)
- D(N) = IF(A(N-1)=1,C(N),D(N-1)+C(N))

**1st :**

- INDEX($D$1:$D$9, MATCH(**1**,$B$1:$B$9, 0))

**2nd :**

- INDEX($D$1:$D$9, MATCH(**2**,$B$1:$B$9, 0))

**3rd :**

- INDEX($D$1:$D$9, MATCH(**3**,$B$1:$B$9, 0))

Hope this helps !